# The flutter permission handler is not executed

Tags: flutter, dart

The flutter permission handler is not executed.

I tried using a handler in the `yaml file`, but it says no plugin. What's the reason? And I want to set up recording, camera, and storage space permissions, but is it all supported?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Your package In Yaml

**follow this step**

[image]

**OR**

**Go to Terminal **

Run this command:

With Flutter:

```
flutter pub add permission_handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your syntax is wrong.

------  add this line ------
`permission_handler: ^8.3.0`

Get newer Version :- [Permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

You can see my pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Read more about YAML Syntax:-

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html